# Start and stop systemd units in the same order

Tags: systemd, start-stop-daemon

How am I supposed to do this in systemd?

```
start unit.A
 started unit.A
start unit.B
 started unit.B

stop unit.A
 stopped unit.A
stop unit.B
 stopped unit.B
```

---

I know `After=/Before=` will order units in reverse on start/stop like AB -> BA, but I need AB -> AB.

My guess is, that I have to merge `unit.A` with `unit.B`, something along the lines of

*unit.A.service:*

```
ExecStartPost=unit.A
```

And handle stop ordering in `ExecStopPost=`.

**EDIT:**

It seemed that a combination of `Upholds=` and `PropagatesStopTo=` would probably give me what I want, or very close, but it turns out, those are added in `systemd version 249`, but I have to get it running on `241`/`247`.

I still have an academic interest in whether `Upholds=` and `PropagatesStopTo=` would have been the right call, had I access to `systemd 249`?

Comment: No. I want to control both the start and the stop order. Basically I want a stop order which is not what After=/Before= enforces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

**thisunit_ExecStartPost.sh:**

```
systemctl start otherunit
```

**thisunit_ExecStop.sh:**

```
systemctl stop otherunit
```

In my case, `otherunit` notices if `thisunit` fails, otherwise stopping `otherunit` may need to be moved to `thisunit_ExecStopPost.sh`, which is generally a better place (but not in my project).